# How to generate complex ORM code and REST API with swagger-codegen?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-codegen, connexion

swagger-editor is with codegen tool built in, so I can generate server side code with it. I try the pet store example, and it works. Then my next try is to think about data persistence. I google around, and I often use Python/Java, so I focus on this 2 languages.

First I would like to try python.

In the swagger-codegen tool, it depends on flask/connexion/flask-swagg and so on, so I think connexion is a good start for me. However when I read the generated code, I found that swagger-codegen inherits swagger data Model itself, and I can use connexion with SQLAlchemy to implement db ORM. For example 
[Connexion-Example](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/tree/master/examples/openapi3/sqlalchemy). Also I found [SAFRS](https://github.com/thomaxxl/safrs) a good place to go, with this I can easily expose all the DB models as REST API, so that I don't need to create duplicate ORM code myself. So I try to find some suggestions, which can help me out, because now I am stuck.

I want to create a API specification file(yaml or json in swagger-editor), and also the DB model. Then generate server side code, including DB model with SQLAlchemy, with all the DB CRUD ops as REST API. My first thinking is to modify swagger template in swagger-codegen, to use SAFRS or connexion. But I would like to discuss here to get some advise on how you manage to do this kind of work?

Thanks.

Andes

Comment: any success regarding this specification/ requirement?